# Get 1 or 0 IF another table value is bigger than 5

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've been trying to do this but I can't figure it out I'm learning SQL Server.

**Table: Characters**

```
AccountID Name   ResetDay ResetWeek
--------------------------------------
Mongus   Golgon    10      15
Treas    Trical    3       10
```

**Table: Logros**

```
AccountID Name   ResetDay ResetWeek
--------------------------------------
Mongus   Golgon    0      0
Treas    Trical    0      0
```

What I need to do is IF in table Characters, column ResetDay value is bigger than 5 then Insert on table Logros, column ResetDay a 1. IF it is not bigger do nothing. It needs to match Name to make sure is giving the data to correct row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server:

```
UPDATE
    L
SET
    ResetDay = 1
FROM
    Logros As L
    INNER JOIN Characters As C
    ON C.AccountID = L.AccountID
    And C.Name = L.Name
WHERE
    C.ResetDay > 5
;
```